# How to optimize a MySQL query which is taking 10 sec to fetch results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-optimization

I have a MySQL database. I have a table in it which has around 200000 rows.

I am querying through this table to fetch the latest data.Query

```
select *
from `db`.`Data`
where
     floor = "floor_value" and
     date = "date_value" and
     timestamp > "time_value"
order by
    timestamp DESC
limit 1
```

It is taking about 9 sec to fetch the data, when the number of rows in the table were less, it did not take this long to fetch the data. Can anyone help me with how do I reduce the time taken for the query?

Comment: Do you have any index in your table? If so mention that as well

Comment: You don't have any indexes on your table. Please take a tutorial on this first.

Comment: Refer to this https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-optimize-mysql-queries-for-speed-and-perfor.

Comment: I am not aware of indexes and currently don't have any indexes, looking into it.

Comment: Use suitable datatypes.  Varchar does not compare nicely against numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following compound index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON Data (floor, date, timestamp);
```

This index should cover the entire `WHERE` clause and also ideally should be usable for the `ORDER BY` clause.  The reason why `timestamp` appears *last* in the index is that this allows for generating a final set of matching timestamp values by scanning the index.  Had we put `timestamp` first, MySQL might have to seek back to the clustered index to find the set of matching timestamp values.